# Authentification methods for non-public facing websites

Tags: windows, security, iis, web-server, authentication

We have two different kinds of websites in our company, one of those are public-faced websites where users have to have access without serverbased authentication (anonymous auth.) and other websites which employees of our company need to access **outside** the network. Those employees work for our external services and need to connect to those websites from all over the country. I split those two different kinds of websites to two different IIS 8.5 Servers.

What I am concerned with now, is the authentication for users on our internal websites and possible intruders which want to access those websites via bruteforce etc.

I read about digest, basic and windows authentication.

As far as I understood, digest authentification works the fastest and needs less server resources than other authentification methods. But for digest authentification the server needs to be in a domain, since it needs to get a hash from a domain controller. I also read it is not possible, to delegate user credentials received via digestauth to the specific website. Like if the user needs to authenticate himself in a login screen inside the website, you can not take the credentials he passed when accessing the server and take those as website login. Since I don't want my users to authentificate themselves two times, this auth-method doesn't fit my needs, if I understood this correctly.

basic authentication sends the password as plain text via base64 "encryption". This is also not very secure since a intruder could simply catch those credentials.

Windows-authentication should be a little more secure than basic authentication, the webserver doesn't need to be in a domain but all the users that need to be authenticated need to be in a users group on the web server. I don't know how the credentials are encoded in this method.

My question would be, which authentication method would you suggest using for this specific case for my internal websites - in a security perspective.

Note: We use SSL (HTTPS) for all our websites, internal and public facing.

Comment: VPN + Kerberos + SPNEGO?